Control axes with encoder or sensor
I want to move the axis using the encoder sensor readings, but when using the encoder my axis rotates suddenly and not gradually.  i used arduino to send encoder data.
i use this encoder

and this happen when i rotate encoder

This is my code:
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

// Variabel untuk menyimpan data encoder
int distance = 0;
double tilt = 0.0;
// Variabel global untuk publisher
ros::Publisher joint_pub;


// Callback untuk menerima data encoder dari Arduino
void distanceCallback(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg) {
    // Callback untuk menerima data encoder dari Arduino
    distance = msg->data;

    // Hitung ulang sudut tilt berdasarkan nilai distance yang baru
     tilt = (distance*(M_PI/180)*10);

    // Deklarasi pesan joint state
    sensor_msgs::JointState joint_state;

    // Update joint state
    joint_state.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    joint_state.name.resize(1);
    joint_state.position.resize(1);
    joint_state.name[0] = "tilt";
    joint_state.position[0] = tilt;

    // Kirim data joint state
    joint_pub.publish(joint_state);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Inisialisasi node ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "arduino_interface");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    // Inisialisasi publisher
    joint_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states", 1);

    // Subscriber untuk menerima data encoder dari Arduino
    ros::Subscriber distance_sub = n.subscribe<std_msgs::Int16>("cart", 1, distanceCallback);

    // Rate untuk loop utama
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10); // 10 Hz

    while (ros::ok()) {
        // Tunggu pembaruan nilai distance
        ros::spinOnce();

        // Tunggu sesuai dengan rate
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}

and this my urdf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="roper">

<link name="base_link"/>


<!--BASE ROBOT-->
<link name="base_robot">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.25 0.20 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "oren">
            <color rgba ="1 0.5 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_link_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child  link="base_robot"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.06"/>
</joint>


<!--BASE DEPAN (KOTAK DIBAWAH1)-->
<link name="base_depan">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
           <box size="0.035 0.04 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "oren">
            <color rgba ="1 0.5 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_robot_to_base_depan" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="base_depan"/>
    <origin xyz="0.095 0.0 -0.02"/>
</joint>


<!--BASE DEPAN (KOTAK DIBAWAH2)-->
<link name="base_depan2">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
           <box size="0.020 0.025 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
       <material name="silver">
        <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1.0"/> <!-- Adjust RGBA values accordingly -->
       </material>

    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_depan_to_base_depan2" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_depan"/>
    <child  link="base_depan2"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.02"/>
</joint>


<!--BAN DEPAN-->
<link name="ban_depan">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
           <cylinder length="0.008" radius="0.011"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_depan_to_ban_depan" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_depan2"/>
    <child  link="ban_depan"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.011"/>
</joint>


<!--BAN BELAKANG KANAN-->
<link name="banr_robot">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.03" radius="0.0325"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "black">
            <color rgba ="0 0 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_robot_to_banr_base" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="banr_robot"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.115 0.115 -0.0325"/>
</joint>


<!--BAN BELAKANG KIRI-->
<link name="banl_robot">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.03" radius="0.0325"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "black">
            <color rgba ="0 0 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_robot_to_banl_base" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="banl_robot"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.115 -0.115 -0.0325"/>
</joint>


<!--TIANG DEPAN KANAN-->
<link name="TD_KANAN">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.005"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="TD_KANAN_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="TD_KANAN"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.05 0.09 0.02"/>
</joint>


<!--TIANG BELAKANG KANAN-->
<link name="TD_KANAN1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.005"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="TD_KANAN1_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="TD_KANAN1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.05 0.09 0.02"/>
</joint>

<!--TIANG DEPAN KIRI-->
<link name="TD_KIRI">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.005"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="TD_KIRI_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="TD_KIRI"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.05 -0.09 0.02"/>
</joint>


<!--TIANG BELAKANG KIRI-->
<link name="TD_KIRI1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.005"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="TD_KIRI1_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="TD_KIRI1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.05 -0.09 0.02"/>
</joint>


<!--BASE ROBOT 2-->
<link name="base_atas">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.15 0.20 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "oren">
            <color rgba ="1 0.5 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="base_atas_to_base_robot" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child  link="base_atas"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.05"/>
</joint>

<!--LINK TIANG CART-->
<link name= "tiangc">
</link>
<joint name="tiangc" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_robot"/>
    <child link="tiangc"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.125 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>



<!-- CART LINK -->
    <link name="cart">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="100" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="100" iyz="0" izz="100"/>
            <origin/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.0125"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius=".005" length=".005"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="oren"/>
            <color rgba ="1 0.5 0 1"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.08"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius=".20" length=".6"/>
            </geometry>
            <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="tilt" type="continuous">
        <parent link="tiangc"/>
        <child link="cart"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit upper="360" lower="0" effort="10" velocity="10"/>
    </joint>


<!--TIANG CART HUBUNG-->
<link name="tchub">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.010 0.1 0.005"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="tchub_to_cart" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="cart"/>
    <child  link="tchub"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.5708" xyz="-0.05 0 0.0125"/>
</joint>       


<!--BASE CART-->
<link name="base_cart">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.25 0.20 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name= "oren">
            <color rgba ="1 0.5 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="tchub_to_base_cart" type= "fixed">
    <parent link="tchub"/>
    <child  link="base_cart"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 -1.5708" xyz="0 0.16 -0.0125"/>
</joint>

<!--IMULINK-->
<!--link name= "imu">
</link>
<joint name="base_link to imu" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu"/>
    <origin xyz="0.23 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-3.14159" upper="3.14159" effort="100" velocity="0.1"/>
</joint-->

<!--LASERLINK-->
<!--link name= "laser">
</link>
<joint name="base_link_to_laser" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="laser"/>
    <origin xyz="0.125 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint-->

<!--MAPODOM-->
<!--link name= "map">
</link>
<joint name="MAP_to_ODOMWHEEL" type="fixed">
    <parent link="map"/>
    <child link="odomwheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint-->
</robot>


You might need to tell us what the problems that you are having (detailed description or error logs?). Please [edit] and update question with any extra info, thanks. Nice screenshot though :-)
